# Environment for ancient Greek poem with comments

Tags: footnotes, greek, line-numbering, poetry

I want to write an ancient Greek poem and I am having problems in setting the right environmental parameters.

[image: Here is a sample of how it should look like]

My major difficulty is to make an effective use of footnotes. Instead of using a superscript the footnote should contain the numbering of the line of the poem where it appears.

I tried to use the teubner package which is supposed to deal with philological texts. It contains the environment "Versis" which works fine with the numbering but it does not even print the footnote with the \footnote{} command. On the other hand the environment "verse" which is used for poems in general, prints the footnote but I am not aware of a way to make the connection to the line numbering I described above.

I am asking thus if you are familiar with some process of tampering with the numbering and footnotes to make this work. Any other advice on how to deal with the task of writing such poems would be highly appreciated! For me this means shifting my work from a cumbersome philological editor to the neat world of LaTeX / Tex.

Many thanks in advance!

Here is a sample of what I tried up to now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,polutonikogreek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}

\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\newcommand{\push}{\ \ \ \ }
\begin{document}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{Quid sum miser tunc dicturus?}
\verselinenumbersleft
\verselinenumfont{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-2em}

\poemtitle{Dies Irae}

\poemlines{5}

\begin{verse}

\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς\footnote{fdsfds} \\
τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
\marginpar{λαλαλα}πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε. \\ 

\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς\footnote{fdsfds} \\
τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε. \\
\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς\footnote{fdsfds} \\
τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε. \\
\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς \\
\flagverse{fdsfsd}τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε. \\
\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς\footnote{fdsfds} \\
τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε. 


\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should share your code (what you've got so far) so we could test and modify it. Welcome ;)

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this can be what you need.

Using the `\getrefnumber` command from the [`refcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount) package, you can replace your footnotes

```
\footnote{fdsfds}
```

with something like

```
\label{verse:1}\footnote[\getrefnumber{verse:1}]{fdsfds}
```

Note that `\label` and `\ref` commands inside the `verse` environment refer to the verse number.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,polutonikogreek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}

\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand{\push}{\ \ \ \ }
\begin{document}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{Quid sum miser tunc dicturus?}
\verselinenumbersleft
\verselinenumfont{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-2em}

\poemtitle{Dies Irae}

\poemlines{5}

\begin{verse}

\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς\label{verse:1}\footnote[\getrefnumber{verse:1}]{fdsfds} \\
τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
\marginpar{λαλαλα}πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε. \\

\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς\label{verse:2}\footnote[\getrefnumber{verse:2}]{fdsfds} \\
τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε. \\
\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς\label{verse:3}\footnote[\getrefnumber{verse:3}]{fdsfds} \\
τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε. \\
\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς \\
\flagverse{fdsfsd}τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε. \\
\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς\label{verse:4}\footnote[\getrefnumber{verse:4}]{fdsfds} \\
τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε.


\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

In order to meet the request in your comments, we can use the [`bigfoot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot) package and define a new type of footnote.

The following lines

```
\SelectFootnoteRule{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\SelectFootnoteRule{default}
```

have to be inserted in order to have

- A footnote rule before the new defined footnote.
- A new type of footnote (`\footnoteA`)
- A footnote rule before the ordinary footnotes.

At this point your `\myfootnote` have to be defined in terms of the new `\footnoteA`:

```
\newcounter{foo}

\newcommand{\myfootnote}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{foo}%
  \label{verse\arabic{foo}}%
  \let\thefootnoteA\relax%
  \footnoteA{\textbf{\ref{verse\arabic{foo}}} #1}%
  }
```

Here is a complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,polutonikogreek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}

\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\SelectFootnoteRule{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\SelectFootnoteRule{default}

\newcounter{foo}

\newcommand{\myfootnote}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{foo}%
  \label{verse\arabic{foo}}%
  \let\thefootnoteA\relax%
  \footnoteA{\textbf{\ref{verse\arabic{foo}}} #1}%
  }

\newcommand{\push}{\ \ \ \ }
\begin{document}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{Quid sum miser tunc dicturus?}
\verselinenumbersleft
\verselinenumfont{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-2em}

\poemtitle{Dies Irae}

\poemlines{5}

\begin{verse}

\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς\myfootnote{fdsfds} \\
τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
\marginpar{λαλαλα}πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε. \\

\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς\myfootnote{fdsfds} \\
τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε. \\
\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς\myfootnote{fdsfds} \\
τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε. \\
\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς \\
\flagverse{fdsfsd}τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε. \\
\push Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς \\
ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος \\
καὶ ἀπόστολος σεπτὸς\myfootnote{fdsfds} \\
τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ, \\
πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε.


\end{verse}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
Here end the verses\footnote{The end}.
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

which yields the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think the use of \ref solved this problem. I actually defined a new footnote command: \newcommand{\myfootnote}[1]{\stepcounter{foo}\label{verse\arabic{foo}}\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{\textbf{\ref{verse\arabic{foo}}} #1}}       which did the trick!

Comment: I was wondering if you also knew some way of making two different types of footnotes. Like foot1, foot2 and then in the end of the page have two lines and under each gather the relevant footnotes. In any case thanks a lot, you made my life easier :)

Comment: @MariosCool see the edit.

Answer (score 3):

The package `eledmac` is really much better for this sort of thing.  If you are going to work with classical Greek, I'd also encourage you to switch to the use of `fontspec` and `polyglossia`; in many (though not all) ways, they are the better choice.  Anyway, if we simplify your example, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
% fonts:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{DejaVu Serif}

% multilingual support
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\setmainlanguage[variant=polytonic]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

% critical edition typesetting:
% (see also eledpar for parallel, 'facing-page', editions)
\usepackage{eledmac}
\let\ac\Afootnote % \Afootnote = \ac = apparatus criticus
\setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{10pt}
% '3' = 3x indent for overlong lines;
% '2' = 2x indentation for first line of each stanza
% '0' = 0x indentation for lines 2-10 of each stanza
\setstanzaindents{3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}


\begin{document}

\beginnumbering

% start each stanza with: \stanza
% end each line with:     &
% end each stanza with:   \&    
\stanza
Ἐν οὐρανοῖς τῷ δεσπότῃ παρεστηκὼς&
\flagstanza[40pt]{67v}ὡς αὐτοῦ διάκονος&
καὶ ἀπόστολος \edtext{σεπτὸς}{\ac{Apparatus criticus}}&
τοὺς ἐν γῇ τιμῶντας υε, Θωμᾶ,\footnoteA{Regular footnote}&
\ledsidenote{λαλαλα}πειρασμῶν παντοδαπῶν βίου διάσωζε.\&

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```